# How to force BOX app user access token to get expire within 60 minutes

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, box

I created BOX app user access token for a user which will get expire after 60 minutes using JWT/OAuth2. I then created new access token for the same user within 60 minutes. How can I force the old access token to expire? Otherwise both access tokens are valid.

Answer (score 1):

You can revoke a Box API access token using the Revoke endpoint. Here is a cURL example:

```
curl https://api.box.com/oauth2/revoke \
-d 'client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID' \
-d 'client_secret=MY_CLIENT_SECRET' \
-d 'token=MY_TOKEN' \
-X POST
```